# Explicit diagonalization of $(e^{i \alpha (k-l)})_{1 \leq k,l \leq N}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Given $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $N \geq 1$, I hope that the matrix
$$A_N := (e^{i \alpha (k-l)})_{1 \leq k,l \leq N}$$
admits a simple reduction $A_N = U^* D U$ with $U^* U = I_N$ and $D$ a diagonal matrix (notation $U^* = \overline{U^{\intercal}}$).

Indeed, $A_N$ is hermitian, so such a reduction exists. My question is : is there a simple expression of $U$ (for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$) ?

I tried to look at circular matrix, but $A_N$ isn't that type of matrix. I suspect this matrix to have a name, but I couldn't find it. I would be happy if you have any hint or reference.

For the context, I would like to diagonalize the matrix $\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i \alpha (k-l)} g(\alpha) d\alpha\Big)_{1 \leq k, l \leq N}$ with $g$ a nice and positive function.

Comment: The rank of $A_N$ is $1$. It does give you a diagonalization of $A_N$.

Comment: The final matrix that you are looking for is a Toeplitz matrix. I don't think you will find easily a closed form diagonalization of it. But you can some nice properties when $N$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Thank you for the name. Do you have any reference for the asymptotic properties? In an ideal world I would like to choose $g$ such that the final matrix is "almost" diagonal (for big N)

Comment: I the previous comment, I wasn't clear enough. I fact in my real problem $g = f h_{\beta}$ with $f$ that can be choosen and $h_{\beta}$ a function that depend on an unknown parameter $\beta$. Thus $h_{\beta} $ can't be choosen (more simply $h_{\beta}(x) = |x|^{\beta}$).

Comment: The best reference I know is https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-93-86279-04-0

Comment: Thank you very much. A part of my question was asking reference for my problem, so you partially answered it. So if you want to elaborate your comment in an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you. But I think the contribution of my comments is not meaningfull to be an answer.